# why is div tag not working with css

Tags: css

I'm having issue styling grid view for my product list page. What i want is to style it in a way that four products will be display on each row and with maximum of three rows per page. Currently, what i have is product displaying vertically. Any help?
My code for product.php is:

```
<?php
                $result=mysql_query("select * from products") or die("select * from products"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>  
        <div id="product-grid"> 
        <div class="product-item">
                <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $row['picture']?>" /></div>
               <div><strong><?php echo $row['name']?></strong></div>
                        <div class="product-description"><?php echo $row['description']?></div>
                        Price:
                            <div class="product-price">$<?php echo $row['price']?></div>
                        <div><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row['serial']?>)" /></div>

            <?php } ?>.
```

My style is something like this but its not having any desirable effect.

```
body{width:610px;}
#product-grid {border-top: #F08426 2px solid;margin-bottom:30px;}
#product-grid .txt-heading{background-color: #FFD0A6;}
.product-item { float:left; background:#F0F0F0; margin:15px;    padding:5px;}
.product-price {color:#F08426;}
.product-image {height:100px;background-color:#FFF;}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex

Checkout demo below

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/oobvms5e/4/)

```
#product-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.product-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin:10px 0 0 10px;    
  width: calc(100% * (1/4) - 12px - 1px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

close `product-item` div u just forgot to close `product-item` div that's why your css is not working.

```
<?php
    $result=mysql_query("select * from products") or die("select * from products"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<div id="product-grid">
    <div class="product-item">
        <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $row['picture']?>" /></div>

        <div><strong><?php echo $row['name']?></strong></div>

        <div class="product-description"> <?php echo $row['description']?> </div>

        Price:
        <div class="product-price">$ <?php echo $row['price']?> </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row['serial']?>)" />
        </div>
    </div> <!--here you forgot-->
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

and apply `overflow:hidden` on `#product-grid` and width as you want width with `float:left` no need to add float:left on  `.product-item` so just remove it

```
#product-grid {
border-top: #F08426 2px solid;
margin-bottom: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o9qgnz79/1/)

**Note**: I recommend to you use product-item as a **class** not **id** always use class for multiple item with same name

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every one that respond to my question. It gave me an insight into fixing the problem. I was able to get my grid working using the below code

```
body {
font-family: "open san", verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.5em;
color: #333;
background: #ffffff;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;}

.prod-box{
    width: 200px; height: 340px;
    padding: 10px; margin: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
}

.prod-box img:first-child, .prod-box-list img:first-child{width: 190px; float: left;}
.prod-box h3 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    width:140px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0;
    color:#888;
    font: italic normal 14px georgia;
    font-style: italic;
}
.prod-box p{ display: none;}

.prod-box .old{
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #be0000 !important;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.prod-box .price{
    width: 60px;
    display: inline; 
    float: left;
    font: italic 13px georgia;
    color: #181818;
}
.prod-box .cart-ico{
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 35px; height: 35px;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.prod-box .cart-ico:hover{
    background-color: #7eb800;
}
```